# Task not running from another task

Tags: c#, asp.net, task, .net-4.5

In .Net 4.5
This methos add a task into a list.

```
//This method returns Datetime.
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessPost(_blockSize), token);
tasks.Add(task);
```

And I want to run another process, but I have an error with `ReturnString` Method.

```
public virtual DateTime ProcessPost(int blockSize)
{
    Interlocked.Add(ref totalToProcess, blockSize);
    DateTime finishTask;
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                bool isSuccess = stackProcesos.TryPop(out documento);
                if (isSuccess)
                {
                    // Verifies if document exist.
                    if (!HelperString.IsNullOrEmpty(documento.ruta) && HelperFile.ExistsFile(documento.ruta)){}
                    else
                    {
                    //In this part ocurrs an error.
                        if (!HelperString.IsNullOrEmpty(documento.number))
                        {
                            ConsultorSTR consultor = new ConsultorSTR();
                            var baseTask = consultor.ReturnString(documento.number, documento.token);
                                    
                            //no execution I don't know why
                            baseTask.Wait();
                                    
                            //other things
                        }
                    };

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {}
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

ReturnString do a PostAsync, but the process never start and never ends.

```
 public async Task<string> ReturnString(string Number, string token)
 {
         var XmlRequestContent = new StringContent($"foo-content", Encoding.UTF8, "text/xml");
         
         //Response never comes
         var response = await client.PostAsync("url/api/returnData", XmlRequestContent);
         return "";
 }
```

`ReturnString` works in another project, but not in this, any solution?

Comment: What kind of error do you mean by _"but I have an error with ReturnString Method."_?  Does it compile, does it throw an exception, does it do (or not do) something unexpected?  Do you intend to not `await` the call to `var baseTask = consultor.ReturnString(documento.number, documento.token);`?

Comment: when the process run PostAsync method, this doesnt execute, it appers to skip the process, and never start it, even if it is in a try catch block, doesnt appear any exception, only after a few minutes appears "task has been cancelated"

Comment: Your code is tossing sync-over-async work onto a thread pool (using a highly questionable API), and seems to have some sort of queue of work involved. In short, there's a lot wrong; what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: If you're getting "task has been canceled" it seems likely that the HTTP request is timing out. Make sure the URL is correct and that it is reachable using an ordinary browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is probably deadlocking, because you are doing sync-over-async. Instead make this code fully async using `await`

You also should remove the empty `catch` blocks so that errors get propogated correctly, and you have a logic error where you are incrementing `totalToProcess` regardless whether you managed to `Pop` or not.

```cs
public virtual async Task<DateTime> ProcessPost(int blockSize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++)
    {
        bool isSuccess = stackProcesos.TryPop(out documento);
        if (!isSuccess)
            break;

        Interlocked.Increment(ref totalToProcess);
        // Verifies if document exist.
        if (!HelperString.IsNullOrEmpty(documento.ruta) && HelperFile.ExistsFile(documento.ruta))
            continue;

        if (!HelperString.IsNullOrEmpty(documento.number))
        {
            ConsultorSTR consultor = new ConsultorSTR();
            await consultor.ReturnString(documento.number, documento.token);
                                    
                //other things
        }
    }
    return someValueHere;
}
```